# i'm not getting any data with httpClient.get Observable in mergeMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

this is what i did

```
constructor(
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private pData: PDataService,
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.combine$ = combineLatest(
     this.route.parent.params,
     this.route.params,
   ).pipe(
     map(([parent, child]) => {
       return { parent, child };
     }),
     tap( val => {
     // did something
     ),
     mergeMap( val => this.pData.getCommentsData(val.parent['id'], val.child['id']))
   ).subscribe( val => console.log(val));
}
```

---

in PDataService

```
getCommentsData(productId, reviewsId) {
   return this.httpClient.get<any>( this.BASE_URL + '/api/products/' + productId + '/reviews/' + reviewsId + '/' );
}
```

But i'm not getting any data through **console.log(val)** from `this.pData.getCommentsData(val.parent['id'], val.child['id']))`

Also, route.event from `this.route.parent.params`,
     `this.route.params`, is not working except at first.

route event should always work. did i code wrong way?

Comment: combineLatest waits until BOTH observables resolve to something before emitting.

Comment: @dmcgrandle Then what is right operator? not combineLatest . i want to emit event when one of observables ( parent or child route ) resolved

Comment: If you just want to emit when either one does then use `merge()`.  If you only want to take a single emission of whoever emits first then do `merge().pipe(take(1))`.  Good explanation [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge)

Comment: @RayKim It looks like you need both source Observables to emit because when calling `getCommentsData` you use both.

Comment: @martin Yes i use both. If one of following observables emit, then previous value
of observable is fine. For example, `Parent.params` emits '1', `child.params` emits '2'. After that `child.params` emits '3'. So the result what I expect is [1, 3]. How to achieve this ?

Comment: try withLatestFrom instead of combineLatest

Comment: The problem is that both `this.route.parent.params` and `this.route.params` because you need both values and I don't know if this is what really happens.

Comment: @Davy you're a lifesaver! It really works. `withLatestFrom` is exactly what i wanted. I really appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: I thought that `this.route` implies `ActivatedRoute`. So I thought that the person who read this question would know what really happens.  If you confused by lack of explanation or anything. Sorry about that. Anyway `withLatestFrom` works!  @martin

Comment: @Raykim glad i could help! :)